# jQuery Accordion Height Conflict With Content

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I am having some problems with my jQuery Accordion. 
It contains a checkbox, a small image and a line of text enclosed in a paragraph tag.

The issue I am having is that I am having to set a height for the UI Accordion in order to see the icons. If I dont set a height, then the Accordion starts to fail by just showing the top line, and even then half of it is missing.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="ui-accordion" id="jQueryUIAccordion">


<h3><a href="#">My Accordion</a></h3>

<div>

<ul class="badList">

<li class="list1">

<input class="accord1" value="layer1" id="check1" type="checkbox" unchececked;" />
<img class="accord" src="img/blue/img1.png" width="33" height="37"></img> 
<p class="list"> Pick Me 1</p>

</li>

<li class="list2">

<input class="accord1" value="layer1" id="check1" type="checkbox" unchececked;" />
<img class="accord" src="img/blue/img2.png" width="33" height="37"></img> 
<p class="list"> Pick Me 2</p>

</li>

<li class="list3">
<input class="accord1" value="layer1" id="check1" type="checkbox" unchececked;" />
<img class="accord" src="img/blue/img3.png" width="33" height="37"></img> 
<p class="list"> Pick Me 3</p>
</li>

<li class="list4">

<input class="accord1" value="layer1" id="check1" type="checkbox" unchececked;" />
<img class="accord" src="img/blue/img4.png" width="33" height="37"></img> 
<p class="list"> Pick Me 4</p>
</li> 

<li class="list5">

<input class="accord1" value="layer1" id="check1" type="checkbox" unchececked;" />
<img class="accord" src="img/blue/img5.png" width="33" height="37"></img> 
<p class="list"> Pick Me 5</p>

</li>

</ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery("#jQueryUIAccordion").accordion({ 
    event: "click",
    collapsible: true,
    autoHeight: true
});
</script>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
/* Layout helpers
----------------------------------*/
.ui-helper-hidden {
display: none;
font-size: small;
}
.ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
position: absolute;
left: -1e+008;
font-size: small;
}
.ui-helper-reset {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
border: 0;
outline: 0;
line-height: 1.3;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: small;
list-style: none;
}
.ui-helper-clearfix:after { content: "."; display: block; height: 0; clear: both; visibility:  hidden; }
.ui-helper-clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* required comment for clearfix to work in Opera \*/
* html .ui-helper-clearfix {
height: auto;
}
.ui-helper-clearfix {
display: block;
width: 250px;
}
/* end clearfix */
.ui-helper-zfix {
width: 250px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
opacity: 0;
filter: Alpha(Opacity=0);
}


/* Interaction Cues
----------------------------------*/
.ui-state-disabled {
cursor: default !important;
}



/* Component containers
----------------------------------*/
.ui-widget { font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 1.1em; border: 2px solid #334A6F; margin: 0 20px 20px 0; background-color: #CCCCCC; }
.ui-widget .ui-widget {
font-size: 1em;
}
.ui-widget input, .ui-widget select, .ui-widget textarea, .ui-widget button {
font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 1em;

}
.ui-widget-content a {
color: #334A6F;
width: 250px;
font-size: small;
}
.ui-widget-header a {
color: #334A6F;
width: 250px;
font-size: small;
}

/* Interaction states
----------------------------------*/
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
border: 1px solid #334A6F;
font-weight: normal;
width: 250px;
font-size: small;
background-color: #001D4B;
}
.ui-state-default a, .ui-state-default a:link, .ui-state-default a:visited {
color: #e3e3e3;
text-decoration: none;
width: 250px;
font-size: small;
}
.ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,     .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus {
border: 1px solid #334A6F;
font-weight: normal;
color: #ffffff;
width: 250px;
font-size: small;
background-color: #334A6F;
}
.ui-state-hover a, .ui-state-hover a:hover {
text-decoration: none;
width: 250px;
font-size: small;
}
.ui-state-active, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active {
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
background: #ffffff;
font-weight: normal;
color: #FFFFFF;
width: 250px;
font-size: small;
}
.ui-state-active a, .ui-state-active a:link, .ui-state-active a:visited {
color: #334A6F;
width: 250px;
font-size: small;
}

----------------------------------*/
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header { cursor: pointer; position: relative; margin-top: 1px; zoom: 1; }
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-li-fix {

}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header-active {
border-bottom: 0 !important;
background-color: #F00;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header a {
display: block;
font-size: 1em;
padding: .5em .5em .5em .7em;
width: 250px;
}
/* IE7-/Win - Fix extra vertical space in lists */
.ui-accordion a {
zoom: 1;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-header .ui-icon {
position: absolute;
left: 0.5em;
top: 50%;
margin-top: 24px;
background-color: #F00;
}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content {
padding: 1em 1em;
border-top: 0;
margin-top: 1px;
position: relative;
top: 1px;
margin-bottom: 1px;
overflow: hidden;
display: none;
zoom: 1;
background-color: #F00;

}
.ui-accordion .ui-accordion-content-active {
display: block;
background-color: #CCC;
height: 125px;
}
----------------------------------*/

ul.badList {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left:20px;
  float: left;
}

ul.badList1 {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left:20px;
  float: left;
  position:absolute;
}

LI.list1 { float: left; left: 5px; top: 1px;  height: 35px;line-height: 45px; list-style-position: outside; padding-left: 20px; position: absolute; width: 200px; }

p.list { margin-left: 45px; margin-top: 6px; padding-bottom: 2px;}

.accord1 { top:8px; left: 4px; position: absolute;}
.accord2 { top:8px; left: 4px; position: absolute;}

img.accord  { border: 0 none; float:left; padding-right:10px; background-repeat: no-repeat;  background-position: 0px 2px 0px 35px; margin-top: 2px; }
img.accord2 { border: 0 none; float:left; padding-right:10px; background-repeat: no-repeat; top: -3px; left: 20px; margin-top: 6px; }

/*----- END -----*/
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I am still learning so please forgive any errors in my code.

Answer (score 1):

Check out your code... You have `unchecked;` in your input tags for the checkboxes, which isn't valid...  If you don't want it checked, then just don't specify the `checked="checked"` attribute.

Also, your `<img/>` tags have a separate closing tag.  Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ALBbZ/).  Finally, I don't believe you have to specify auto height in the javascript...  I believe it is the default setting.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you. Will check out and let you know how I get on  :)

Comment: I tried that, thanks for helping me clean up my code! :) 
It is still not working though. I have set a height in my css to 156px, but when I set to auto it is not displaying correctly.
It sort of cuts through half of the text and the image.
Its like half displayed, and half hiding under the accordion if that sounds correct?

Comment: Is this hosted somewhere publicly accessible?

Comment: Hi there, no not at the moment its not.
Just in the middle of getting (or trying) to get it ready for the upload.
Just want to iron out these teething problems you see.
Stay there...

Comment: So, it sounds like one of your CSS rules are to blame for the problem.  I would highly suggest looking into how to use the developer tools in your browser to look at the box layout for the offending item on the DOM.  You can then travel up/down the dom to find the actual offending element, and then using the trace styles option, find which of the CSS values is causing the problems.

Comment: Nice one will do!! I will have a site ready soon so if you dont mind checking back you will be able to see it if thats okay?